# how to remove url in python colab?

Tags: python, regex, dataset, google-colaboratory

I am doing data cleaning for my dataset.
How to remove the link "pic.twitter.com...." in Python for colab?
[here's the picture of the link I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9kv8.jpg)

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#remove other links
def removelinks(text):
  
**  links = re.sub(r'????')**
  return links.sub(r'',text)
  train_df['clean tweet']= train_df['clean tweet'].apply(lambda x:  removelinks(x))
train_df.head()
```

Comment: You should give an example of the text you want to remove. In the text of the question.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TnV1qV/1)):

```py
df['clean tweet'] = df['clean tweet'].str.replace(r'pic\.twitter\.com\S*\s*', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   clean tweet
0  some tweet1
1  some tweet2
2  some tweet3
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
                             clean tweet
0                            some tweet1
1  pic.twitter.com/some_link some tweet2
2                            some tweet3
```